# Why am I getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined here

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am trying to hide the blank rows in this table. The table can display a max of 4 rows at a time so if count is equal to 2 I only want 2 rows to be shown...I must be missing something very obvious here. I review all the similar questions on Stackoverflow and other forums but none provided an answer...can anyone see what is the problem here. BTW...The solution is not to set an ID to the elements and do a getElementById..I tried that. I am actually passing the **count** variable in a res.render()...but hard coded here for convenience. I would appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>

 <style>

    body {
        margin-top:30px;
    }
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }

 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var count=2;

    var activerows=document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");



    for (var i=0; i<activerows.length; i++) {
        activerows[i].style.display='block';
     }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <table class="table table-striped table-border" id="dealers">

            <tbody>

                <tr class="hidden active">
                    <th>A</th>    
                    <th>B</th>  
                    <th>C</th>
                    <th>D</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2/td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4m</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="more" id="more">
        <button type="submit" class="fbtn btn-default">More....</button>    
      </div>


     </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your script come after the table?

Comment: And where does `dealers` come from?

Comment: The dealer line can be ignored it was left over from simplfiying the actual code

Comment: I will try moving the script but it doesn't, seem logical to me since I want this to be done before the table is loaded

Comment: @MichaelE before the table is loaded there are no rows in the table - you have to load the table then run the script

Comment: Ok I did that and the undefined did go away but the style.display though set did not execute .....my thought (just leaning this stuff) was that the style had to execute before the table was loaded ...guess I was wrong...it would seem that I need to execute the style afterwards...with a function call maybe...can you guys assist...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2u84p5Lg/3/) here you have your code to display only `tr` that you want to display by changing your `count` variable. So if `count` is equal to 3 it will display only 3 `tr`

Comment: @edisoni1337 if I am understanding you I would place the code in the addEventListener function that would fire when the DOM is loaded.....would that also cause the style.display new value to take effect.? If this is the case then would it matter where I place the script?

Comment: The code inside this event will fire up when the dom has finished loading and then it doesn't matter where you place this code. But it's suggested to place at the end of your document even if you have other external scripts because the dom doesn't have to wait until your js is loaded

Comment: the issue of speeding up the DOM loading makes a lot of sense and a valid reason for placing the script after. I actually tried your suggestion and the script did execute but I got the same error....'style, of undefined ' once the activerows[] line is executed

Comment: check my jsfiddle please

Comment: @edisoni.1337.....it works. I am not sure why yet...guess I will do some research. Thanks for assisting a newbie I am very grateful.

Comment: It works because the script is in the end of the document. if you place it on top it will again not work so just place at the end. I have also make an control if the count is bigger than how many tr you have then all the tr will be displayed. Vote up and check as correct if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the activerows length as limit of the for. Probably you are reading more elements that the array actually have

Comment: As the other guy said, you should include your script after the part with the html elements you want to manage. Alternatively you can use the ajax $(document).ready() that make the code run only when the page is fully loaded.